# jQuery - mouseover() / fadeIn() not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

http://jsfiddle.net/rR6gC/

I am trying to display information inside a bar whenever somebody pushes their mouse over each bar, but it's not working at all. I was able to make it react from pure CSS, but when trying to use jQuery function, nothing worked.

JavaScript / jQuery

```
$('.score').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).fadeIn('slow');
});
$('.score').mouseeleave(function () {
    $(this).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

CSS

```
.score{
color:white;
font-size:2em;
width:100%;
text-align:center;
display:inline-block;
position:relative;
}
```

Comment: has a error on the code:  Object [object Object] has no method 'mouseeleave'

Comment: You got a typo: `mouseleave(`, not `mouseeleave(` (notice the two `ee`).

Comment: What div are you trying to display when you hover over the bar?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

From what I can understand you want to hide `5` and show it when mouse is over the bar

1. There was a typo in `mouseeleave`
2. You need to write the mouseenter and mouseleave event for the bar wrapper element and then show/hide the score element within it when mouse enters/leaves

Try

```
$('.scoreWrap2 .score').hide()
$('.scoreWrap2').mouseover(function () {
    $(this).find('.score').stop(true, true).fadeIn('slow');
});
$('.scoreWrap2').mouseleave(function () {
    $(this).find('.score').stop(true, true).fadeOut('slow');
});
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/hhR4w/)